# How to add checks for multiple specific ssl_client_fingerprints in Nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, ssl, client-certificate

In addition to usual CA chain validation, I would like Nginx `server` section to permit specific client certificate thumbprints only.

I could find how to check for single fingerprint, but I'm not sure how to combine multiple fingerprints because Nginx does not support `or`, and `map` is not allowed inside `server` sections.

So, now I have an ugly workaround like this:

```
    ssl_client_certificate /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/trusted_chain.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 3;

    if ( $ssl_client_fingerprint = "12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a1" ) {
        set $whiteclient 1;
    }
    if ( $ssl_client_fingerprint = "12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a2" ) {
        set $whiteclient 1;
    }
    if ( $ssl_client_fingerprint = "12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a3" ) {
        set $whiteclient 1;
    }
    if ( $whiteclient != 1 ) {
         return 403;
    }
```

Is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: How is `map` being unavailable in `server` sections a problem here? You are checking SHA1 hashes of certs signed by a known entity, would be quite odd to encounter collisions there..

Comment: @anx  if `map` was available, I could avoid those ugly `if`s. Also, I hoped that some better, built-in way to create a fingerprint whitelist exists.

Comment: This is something you should use a `map` for. They don't go in `server` blocks. They go outside `server` blocks.

Comment: But if `ssl_client_certificate` and `ssl_verify_client` are both defined inside only one  `server` block (because I have multiple server sections), will a `map` outside still work correctly with the `$ssl_client_fingerprint` variable? Will Nginx process this variable when it haven't yet routed the request to the `server` section that enables client certificate processing?

Answer (score 0):

NGINX supports regex matching within [`if` conditions](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) so you can do the following:

```
if ($ssl_client_fingerprint !~ "12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a1|12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a2|12a4f0abc935cc0dd0f6fdcc0d56682d7f5c15a3") {
  return 403
}
```

Obviously this line could get *rather long* but dependant on taste/use case it may be preferable.

Comment: remind the if is bad on nginx because it can speed down all things

Comment: @djdomi Thanks. Would you be able to provide a source for that info please?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/